# is there any way a pug file can talk to sass file?

Tags: html, css, sass, pug

Is there any way I can send data from my pug main file to sass mixin file?
in my project, there is a pug main file that calls a component which is stored in another pug file . The component pug file has a sass file which uses a mixin located in another sass file where all the other mixins are placed.(ie,main.pug has component.pug file which has a sass file where a mixin is called from mixin.scss file) what I need to know is that is there any way I can send data from my main.pug to mixin.scss so that it can easily be reused

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As a view file Template, in charge to help with displaying and structuring the data ...it can receive, I doubt that a .pug file could send out data to another file.